# Headless automation of a router login/restart is failing on the server but working locally using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, networking, phantomjs, casperjs, browser-automation

I have a script that works from Bash and CasperJS which constantly pings my servers. If all servers are down, the modem is restarted using a CasperJS script. From experience, when the issue occurs, external machines can still ping our modem, but internal machines lose internet access. All machines are running on Ubuntu.

Both scripts work fine when run locally, but when running on an external server, the CasperJS fails with the following error:

> CasperError: Cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector: xpath selector: /html/body/form/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/input

The above error is relating the the button that is clicked to restart the modem.

The script takes screenshots at regular intervals, and when run from the server, the screenshot shows that the script becomes stuck when logging into the router's web GUI. The credentials are entered correctly, but they are not accepted, saying the username and password is not recognised. The modem GUI has a log in form, not an authentication popup.

This happens when I use the URL and the external IP address to access the page; but again, only from the server, not my local machine. I am unsure if this may be an issue relating to my code, or the web GUI for the modem.

My CasperJS code is below, edited for security reasons.

```
var casper = require('casper').create()
var x =require('casper').selectXPath;

casper.start('http://router-webpage.com/);

casper.thenClick(x('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[1]/input'), function() {
    this.sendKeys('#username', 'USERNAME');
    this.sendKeys('#password', 'PASSWORD');
    casper.capture('creds.png');
});

casper.thenClick(x('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[3]/a'), function() {

});

casper.wait(5000, function() {
    casper.capture('logged.png');
});

casper.thenOpen('http://router-webpage.com/settings/restart/', function() {

});

casper.wait(5000, function() {
    casper.capture('rebootpage.png');

});

casper.thenClick(x('/html/body/form/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/input'), function() {
    console.log('Clicked reboot');

});

casper.wait(10000, function() {
    casper.capture('rebootconf.png');
    console.log('Confirmation popup loaded');
});

casper.thenClick(x('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/a[1]'), function() {
    console.log('Reboot submitted');
});


casper.run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved.

Connecting from an internal address allowed instant access through the domain name or IP address, but externally, the port had to be explicitly stated in order to give access.

The scripts are now working properly from the server.